# Validate date field in asp.net using validator control

Tags: asp.net, regex, validation, date, comparevalidator

I have the following **validator** control in my page.

```
<asp:CompareValidator ID="cvPatientDateOfBirth" runat="server"
        ControlToValidate="txtPatientDateOfBirth"  
        ErrorMessage="Enter proper date.(DD/MM/YYYY)" 
        Font-Bold="True" Operator="GreaterThan"  Display="Dynamic"
        ValidationGroup="FirstPreview" CssClass="validatorMsg" 
        SetFocusOnError="True" ValueToCompare="1/1/1100" Type="Date" >
    </asp:CompareValidator>
```

- When I type 12/09/1900 it is validating properly. [Good]
- When I type 12/09/1009 it is not validating properly. [Good]
- When I type 12/09/09 it is validating. [Not intended]. In this case I want it to validate only if year of date in 4 digits. Otherwise show error message.

If I use both **compare validator** for date type check and **regular expression validator** for years(4digit) check, then "12/02/198" is showing error message for both the validators.

Can anyone please tell me how to do that?

Thanks.

Comment: The answer by Aghilas Yakoub is working. But I wonder if there is any way we can do it using Compare validator. If anyone has any idea regarding how this can be done using Compare validator please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regular expression is working properly

```
^(0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](19|20)\d\d$
```

Comment: This regular expression is working as per my need. It is allowing years of 4 digits only. Also we cannot have dates greater that 31 and months greater than 12.

Answer (score 4):

You can use RegularExpressionValidator  and set `ValidationExpression`

```
ValidationExpression = "\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}/\d{4}"
```

Comment: But if date is entered as "50/50/1900" it is validating this. Where as this is not a valid date .

Comment: I'am sorry , i'am not here, try with this ^(((0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])\/(0[13578]|1[02])\/((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|((0[1-9]|[12]\d|30)\/(0[13456789]|1[012])\/((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|((0[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])\/02\/((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|(29\/02\/((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|((16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$

Comment: Can you please add the validation expression only as a comment? I doubt what is that $ at the end of your comment.
Thanks.